# Running interactive container with power shell

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to setup an automated build container in Windows(host and guest). Right now I'm having problems executing a simple powershell inside the container. I've done the following:

Created this DockerFile:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Executed this build command:

```
docker build -t test:latest .
```

Started the docker with this command:

```
docker run test
```

The PowerShell prints this and the container exits:

```
PS C:\>

D:\repo\docker\Teste
```

Tried again with this command:

```
docker start d05ee -ai
```

The PowerShell prints the same output:

```
PS C:\>

D:\repo\docker\Teste
```

I wish to use the container interactively in a first moment to validate the tools I will install on it, but I'm not able to do that. I don't now which error is blocking me to do it and that is my question.

Obs1: The powershell in a windows cmd with the same parameters work fine.

Obs2: I've based my DockerFile on the one in [this tutorial.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2017)

Obs3: Running this works fine:

```
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Therefore I presume the problem is on the image generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run your container with the `-it` switch. this will make you container interactive, so you can poke around

```
 docker run -it test
```

Comment: So if I don't run it first time with `-it`, will I never be able to use it interactively?

Comment: well, for that you have to launch it so it never exits. if the process in the docker stops\exits - container will stop. you dont have to launch it with -it first time, but it has to not exit